# store the output of the system() call to a variable

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I use system() function in a C program to get a string. But the system() functions actually displays the output and returns an integer value(0 on successful execution). But what I want is that the output of the system() function has to be stored to a string variable. eg:

```
char a[5];
a = system("echo \"hi\"");
printf("The string is: %s",a);
```

This kind of thing where `a` stores the value `hi` and the output is `The string is: hi`
Please help. Thanks in advance. Operating platform: Linux

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to store the output of system() call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549448/how-to-store-the-output-of-system-call)

Answer (score 3):

You need (or at least want) to use [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) instead of `system` for this. It doesn't store the output directly to a string though -- it gives you a file handle from which you can read the output from the child. It's up to use to use something like `fgets` to read the data from there into a string.

Answer (score 2):

system() will only provide you the exit status.

If you want to get what's printed on STDOUT, you need to make sure you've got another file descriptor which you can read from, and that captures this output. Typically, you do that with the `pipe()` command first (create the connected descriptor) prior to `fork` and then `dup(pipin, 0)` to force one of pipe()'s output to become STDOUT for the child process.

`popen()` may help too.